# Same power cord for Magsafe 2 and Lightning

Tags: power, magsafe, lightning

I have a Mac Air 13" and an iPhone 5. Is there a power cord / adapter that will work for both of them? My goal is to be able to plug one power cord into both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - there isn't. MagSafe is a 5 pin (mirrored - so really three total pins) for high current and wattage charging. The other is a 16 pin, much more adaptable digital interface that can embed USB as well as carry data and charging and audio signals.

Newer USB-C Charging MacBooks will charge over the same sort of USB power delivery that Lightning is supporting - to the future you wish will be here as soon as you step away from MagSafe based hardware.

See these similar questions for more details and possible options:

- [Magsafe to USB-C converter for charging Macbook Pro 2016](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225339/magsafe-to-usb-c-converter-for-charging-macbook-pro-2016)
- [Is it safe to use this 60W PD charged for a late 2016 MacBook Pro 13"?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/264760/is-it-safe-to-use-this-60w-pd-charged-for-a-late-2016-macbook-pro-13)

Comment: Is there any adapters that can do this (and convert the high power from the magsafe power cord to that of a lightning power cord)?

Comment: @Darthlegos Plug the lightning cord into the Mac. When the Mac is charging or connected to power via MagSafe it should charge over USB. Unless you consider a product like the PlugBug "one cable" since it uses one power outlet to both charge usb and power the MagSafe transformer. https://www.twelvesouth.com/product/plugbug-world